# Register user using Laravel - Unauthenticated error, but user is added to database

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, registration, laravel-passport

I am new in Laravel, and I am trying to setup API for user registration.

I'm using Auth/RegisterController and route:

```
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

My Auth/RegisterController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
  }
}
```

This file is using RegistersUsers:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

trait RegistersUsers
{
use RedirectsUsers;

/**
 * Show the application registration form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('auth.register');
}

/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}

/**
 * Get the guard to be used during registration.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard();
}

/**
 * The user has been registered.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
  protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
  {
    //
  }
}
```

I just have to note that those files are autmatic generated when I added Auth to my Laravel projct. I haven't changed sny single line in these files.

My routes/api.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

When I try to register user using

```
api/register
```

I send parameters name, email, password and password_confirmation.

As a header, I have setup:

```
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I send post request and get response 401 (Unauthorized):

```
{
     "error": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

But, the user is saved in database. When I try to send this request again with same data, I get response 422 - Unprocessable Entity

```
{
     "email": 
     [
          "The email has already been taken."
     ]
}
```

If I try to remove

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

It doesn't fix anything

My question is, **Why I get *401 (Unauthorized) error if the response should be 200 - success, since the user is saved in users table in database?**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please copy your code post process,,,

Comment: I'm not sure what to copy?

Comment: Can you paste the `Auth\RegisterController` and your routes.php file ? It's clearly a middleware bug.

Comment: We should see your code. but my wild guess is that you have created the user in your function and then redirect to a view which needs user to be logged in. Please note after you have saved new user you should login the user. `$user = User::create(request()->only(['email', 'password'])` and after that `Auth::login($user)` then at the end you return response.

Comment: Copy your code here

Comment: I've updated my question. Just to note that I haven't written any single line in code, since all code is generated automatic.